# Keeping a transition animation when onBackPressed() has been overwritten

Tags: java, android, android-transitions, onbackpressed

I'm using the following transition animation to go from activityA to activityB:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, activityB.class);
    ImageView myImage = view.findViewById(R.id.myImage);
    ActivityOptions activityOptions = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, myImage, "myImage");
    startActivity(intent,activityOptions.toBundle());
```

When on activityB, when I press back the transition animation is still working. However on activityB I need to override onBackPressed:

```
    @Override
    public void finish() {
        super.finish();
        Log.d("myTag", "finish: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
    }
```

But then when I press back on activityB the transition animation is not applied anymore.

How can I keep transition animation effect on back pressed when onBackPressed has been overwritten?

Answer (score 0):

You Can follow below code:

First you are using like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityFirst.this, ActivitySecond.class);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.left_out);
```

Now you can use animation onBackPressed() like this:

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_in, R.anim.right_out);
            finish();
           }
```

Comment: yes but I'd like to use the specific function makescenetransitionanimation for my animation, I doubt i can transform it to an anim file